# angular2-query-builder ZoneAwarePromise

Tags: angular

I have a problem with angular2-query-builder in angular.

This is my querybuilder.components.ts-file

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { QueryBuilderConfig } from "angular2-query-builder";
import { QueryBuilderModule } from "angular2-query-builder";
import { AuthService } from '../../services/auth.service';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { FlashMessagesService } from 'angular2-flash-messages';
@Component({
  selector: 'query-builder',
  templateUrl: './querybuilder.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./querybuilder.component.css']
})
export class QuerybuilderComponent implements OnInit {
  user: any;
  isDev: boolean;
  authToken: any;
  query = {
    condition: 'and',
    rules: [
      { field: 'age', operator: '<=', value: 'Bob' },
      { field: 'gender', operator: '>=', value: 'm' }
    ]
  };

  config: QueryBuilderConfig = {
    fields: {
      age: { name: 'Age', type: 'number' },
      gender: {
        name: 'Gender',
        type: 'category',
        options: [
          { name: 'Male', value: 'm' },
          { name: 'Female', value: 'f' }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
  constructor(
    private authService: AuthService,
    private router: Router,
    private flashMessage: FlashMessagesService
  ) { }

  ngOnInit() { }
}
```

And here my querybuilder.component.html

```
<query-builder [(ngModel)]="query" config="config"></query-builder>
```

If I want to try it, I get a **ZoneAwarePromise**:

Here follows the original error message:

```
RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded at callWithDebugContext 
(http://localhost:8080/vendor.bundle.js:54717:13) at 
Object.debugCreateComponentView [as createComponentView] 
(http://localhost:8080/vendor.bundle.js:54054:12) at createViewNodes 
(http://localhost:8080/vendor.bundle.js:53400:46) at callViewAction 
(http://localhost:8080/vendor.bundle.js:53865:13) at execComponentViewsAction 
(http://localhost:8080/vendor.bundle.js:53774:13) at createViewNodes 
(http://localhost:8080/vendor.bundle.js:53463:5) at callViewAction 
(http://localhost:8080/vendor.bundle.js:53865:13) at execComponentViewsAction    
(http://localhost:8080/vendor.bundle.js:53774:13) at createViewNodes 
(http://localhost:8080/vendor.bundle.js:53463:5) at callViewAction 
(http://localhost:8080/vendor.bundle.js:53865:13) at execComponentViewsAction 
(http://localhost:8080/vendor.bundle.js:53774:13) at createViewNodes 
(http://localhost:8080/vendor.bundle.js:53463:5) at callViewAction 
(http://localhost:8080/vendor.bundle.js:53865:13) at execComponentViewsAction 
(http://localhost:8080/vendor.bundle.js:53774:13) at createViewNodes 
(http://localhost:8080/vendor.bundle.js:53463:5)
```

What I am doing wrong? 
Thanks and have a nice weekend.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution.
I didn't add the js-imports in index.html and the app.module.ts part.

[`https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular2-query-builder`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular2-query-builder)

[`https://plnkr.co/edit/fgw8tfnOJ1cI48nr3MUl?p=preview`](https://plnkr.co/edit/fgw8tfnOJ1cI48nr3MUl?p=preview)